# Where I can find example of SQLite database file or dump of it?

Tags: sqlite

I really need a sqlite database file for studies.
I'm creating an application in C# and I need a database with many tables, field, views, indexes, constraints and so on. And I don't want to create it myself using sqlite command line tool.

So I suppose may be someone can say where I can find such file, may be different applications or examples, or even can send me their own database file. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are a Pokémon fan you can get [veekun's Pokédex](http://veekun.com/static/pokedex/downloads/veekun-pokedex.sqlite.gz), which is around 30mb and contains all the info up to Pokémon Black and White 2.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There is a nice sample database called Chinook. It's trying to be the modern example to replace NorthWind. They have versions for different database servers including SQLite.

- Homepage, DB diagram, etc.. http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/
- Github (seems more updated than CodePlex) https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database
- Latest SQLite download to date of post: https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/releases/view/55681#fileDownload6
- Download SQLite Sample Database to get the Chinook database file directly http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/
- More SQLite related projects and samples on CodePlex http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=sqlite&ac=8

Also, check this sample in the SQLite .NET client forums (attached to first post)

- [<strike>Getting the Microsoft EFQuerySamples project to work with SQLite</strike>](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/1377.aspx)

Maybe a GUI tool to create database stuff will make starting easier, check this one, free for personal use

- http://www.sqliteexpert.com/

Personally, I create SQLite databases for testing NHibernate mappings. Usually I create my classes and mappings then use the mappings to generate schema to a new SQLite file (or in memory database, more often) and use that. Most NHibernate introduction articles do that as well.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is whidely used by many applications so I am pretty sure very lot examples can be found on your computer. For example, on my Win10 PC if I search in "c:\Users\Konstantin" (my profile) for files with:

- file name mask: ***.sqlite;*.db**
- text inside: **SQLite format 3**

I am currently getting 785 results. Most of them, which have that text in the beginning - it is 99% SQLite database files. Particularly I see that it is used by skype, viber, dropbox, office and firefox.

Answer (score -2):

I used sqlightCrud operation

First creat database class.
    package com.db;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataBaseSampleActivity {

    /** for database */ 
    static final String DataBaseName = "EmployeDB";

     /** for employee table */
    static final String EmployeTable = "Employees";
    static final String ColEmpID = "EmpId";
    static final String ColEmpName = "EmpName";
    static final String ColEmpAge = "EmpAge";
    static final String ColDept = "Dept";

     /** for department table */
    static final String DeptTable = "Department";
    static final String ColDeptID = "DeptId";
    static final String ColDeptName = "DeptName";

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    //private static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String EMPLOYEE_TABLE_CREATE ="Create table " + EmployeTable +
    //"(_id INTEGER UNIQUE," + [old code]
    "("+ColEmpID     + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
    ColEmpName   + " VARCHAR(15) ," +
    ColEmpAge    + " INT(15) ," +
    ColDept      + " VARCHAR(15)) ";

    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DataBaseSampleActivity(Context ctx){
        Log.i("test****", "**test***");
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DataBaseName , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            Log.i("context","context");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(EMPLOYEE_TABLE_CREATE);
            Log.i("************", "table created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.w("tag", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "+ newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EmployeTable);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    };

    public DataBaseSampleActivity open() throws SQLException{
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.i("open", "message");
        return this;
    }
    public void close(){
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //public long insert(Integer empid, String empname, Integer empage, String empdept) {
    public long insert(String empname, Integer empage, String empdept) {
        Log.i("**** suruchitest **** ","*** test ***");
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

        //initialValues.put(ColEmpID, empid);
        initialValues.put(ColEmpName, empname);
        initialValues.put(ColEmpAge, empage);
        initialValues.put(ColDept, empdept);

        return db.insert(EmployeTable, null, initialValues);
    }

    public Cursor getEmpValues(){
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(EmployeTable, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        return mCursor;
    }

    public boolean deleteEmpList(long rowId){
        Toast.makeText(context, "deleted", 2000).show();
        return db.delete(EmployeTable, ColEmpID +" = " + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
    public boolean updateEmplist(String empname, Integer empage, String empdept, Integer rowid){

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        Log.i("#####  "+rowid,""+empname+" "+empage+" "+empdept);

        //initialValues.put(ColEmpID, rowid);
        initialValues.put(ColEmpName,empname);
        initialValues.put(ColEmpAge,empage);
        initialValues.put(ColDept,empdept);

        try{
            int b = db.update(EmployeTable, initialValues,  ColEmpID+ " = " + rowid, null);
            Log.i("update", "up "+rowid+"  ddd   "+b);
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("asdfasdfsadfasdf", "_--___--__--_=-_");
            return false;
        }
    }
}




2. create Main Activity


package com.db;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button buttonsubmit;
    EditText empid,empname,empage,empdept;

    String emp_name, emp_dept;
    //Integer emp_id,emp_age;
    Integer emp_age;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        buttonsubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        buttonsubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

       // empid =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.empid);
        empname =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.empname);
        empage =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.empage);
        empdept =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.empdpt);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         DataBaseSampleActivity dbObj = new DataBaseSampleActivity(getApplicationContext());

           // String Emp_ids = empid.getText().toString();        
           // emp_id = Integer.parseInt(Emp_ids);
            //emp_id = empid.getText().toString();  

            String Emp_ages = empage.getText().toString();
            emp_age = Integer.parseInt(Emp_ages);

            //emp_age = empage.getText().toString();

            emp_name = empname.getText().toString();
            emp_dept = empdept.getText().toString();


         try {
                Log.i("try", "message");
                dbObj.open();
                //long temp = dbObj.insert(emp_id, emp_name, emp_age, emp_dept);
                long temp = dbObj.insert(emp_name, emp_age, emp_dept);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "temp"+temp, 3000).show();
                dbObj.close();

                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ShowListView.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.i("catch", "message");
            }
    }
}





2. Create listclass to show tha data


package com.db;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.integer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ShowListView extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> arrname = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrage = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrdept = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrRowId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrDelId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Array[] arr;
    Button deleteBtn;
    Button btnadd;
    int index = 0;

    public int pos;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.emplist);

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LIST VIEW", 5000).show();

        ToGetCursorValues();

    }

    public void ToGetCursorValues(){
        DataBaseSampleActivity db = new DataBaseSampleActivity(getApplicationContext());
        db.open();
        try {
            Cursor cur = db.getEmpValues();
            cur.moveToFirst();
            arrRowId.clear();
            arrname.clear();
            arrage.clear();
            arrdept.clear();
            while (!cur.isAfterLast()) {
                arrRowId.add(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(db.ColEmpID)));
                arrname.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(db.ColEmpName)));
                arrage.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(db.ColEmpAge)));
                arrdept.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(db.ColDept)));
                cur.moveToNext();
            }
            //Log.i("#####","col "+arrlist.size());
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "* "+arrname.size()+","+arrage.size()+","+arrdept.size(), 5000).show();

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "***** "+arrRowId.get(0), 2000).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }


        ListView lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        lst.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

        db.close();
    }

    public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener,OnClickListener{
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public ListAdapter(Context c){
            Log.i("Context","Context");
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //return 0;
            return arrname.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
        class ViewHolder{
            TextView empnameview;
            TextView empageview;
            TextView empdeptview;
            CheckBox empchkbox;
        }

         // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            Log.i("*view","view*");
            ViewHolder vh;
            //ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

                Log.i("*null1*","*null1*");

                vh = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist, null);

                Log.i("*null2*","*null2*");
                pos = position;
                vh.empnameview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ename);
                vh.empageview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eage);
                vh.empdeptview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edept);
                vh.empchkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ckekDelete);

                Log.i("*null3*","*null3*");

                vh.empnameview.setText(arrname.get(position));

                vh.empnameview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ShowListView.this,UpdateDB.class);
                        String name = arrname.get(position);
                        int age = Integer.parseInt(arrage.get(position));
                        String dept = arrdept.get(position);
                        int rowid = arrRowId.get(position);

                        intent.putExtra("KeyName" , name);
                        intent.putExtra("Keyage" , age);
                        intent.putExtra("Keydept" , dept);
                        intent.putExtra("Rowid", rowid);

                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                vh.empageview.setText(arrage.get(position));
                vh.empdeptview.setText(arrdept.get(position));
                vh.empchkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OnChecked"+position, 2000).show();
                        if(buttonView.isChecked()){
                            arrDelId.add(arrRowId.get(position));
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OnChecked"+position, 2000).show();

//                          DataBaseSampleActivity db = new DataBaseSampleActivity(getApplicationContext());
//                          db.open();
//                          db.deleteEmpList(arrRowId.get(position));
//                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "delet", 3000).show();
//                          db.close();
//                                  
                        }
                        else{
                            for(int i=0;i<arrDelId.size();i++){
                                if(arrRowId.get(position) == arrDelId.get(i)){
                                    arrDelId.remove(i);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                Log.i("******", "complete");

            } else {
                Log.i("*not*","*not*");
                vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            deleteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delBtn);
            deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

            btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
            btnadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent inte = new Intent(ShowListView.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(inte);
                }
            });

           // imageView.setImageResource(thumbarr[position]);
           return convertView;

        }

        public View getView1(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            for(int i=0;i<arrDelId.size();i++){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OnDeleteClick  "+i, 2000).show();
                DataBaseSampleActivity db = new DataBaseSampleActivity(getApplicationContext());
                db.open();
                db.deleteEmpList(arrDelId.get(i));
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "delet", 3000).show();
                db.close();
            }

            ToGetCursorValues();

        }
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    }

}


3. for update 

package com.db;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UpdateDB extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Intent intnt;
    EditText editname,editage,editdept;
    Button updateBtn;
    int row_id;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        editname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.empname);
        editage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.empage);
        editdept = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.empdpt);

        updateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        updateBtn.setText("Update");

        intnt = getIntent();

        editname.setText(intnt.getStringExtra("KeyName"));
        editage.setText(""+intnt.getIntExtra("Keyage",0));
        editdept.setText(intnt.getStringExtra("Keydept"));

        row_id = intnt.getIntExtra("Rowid", 0);

        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "update", 3000).show();
                DataBaseSampleActivity db = new DataBaseSampleActivity(getApplicationContext());
                db.open();
                String empname = editname.getText().toString();
                int empage = Integer.parseInt(editage.getText().toString());
                String empdept = editdept.getText().toString();
                //db.deleteEmpList(row_id);
                db.updateEmplist(empname, empage, empdept,row_id);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "delet", 3000).show();
                db.close();
                Intent list = new Intent(UpdateDB.this,ShowListView.class);
                startActivity(list);
            }
        });

       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "update "+intnt.getIntExtra("Keyage",0), 3000).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```